# How can I generate a random number (or Cell) within a given range? Witout using the same result twice?

Tags: excel-2010, random-access

I am trying to generate a random Cell from specific range:

I need to each cell Row to generate a random selection from a a specific column (range)

below is a picture of my set up and my failed attempts:

[image]

Comment: UPDATE:  I need to randomly select a cell value from the range A2:A21 for the named headers "w-1, w-2, w-3, w-4, w-5, and w-6"  and I cannot use a selected value more than once.  Thank you for any help I can get!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like this:

1. Add a random number next to your data set using `=RAND()`.  I've used column `B`, but you can put it wherever you like.
2. Add this formula to cells `C2` to `H2`

   ```
   =INDEX($A$2:$A$21,RANK.EQ(INDEX($B$2:$B$21,COLUMN()-2),$B$2:$B$21))
   ```

How it works:

- `RAND()` returns a random number in the range `[0..1)`  This is used as a random sort order for your data
- Breaking down the formula:

  - `COLUMN()-2` returns a sequential number `1..6` for columns `C` to `H`
  - `INDEX($B$2:$B$21, ... )` returns the `1st` to `6th` number from the random number list
  - `RANK.EQ( ... ,$B$2:$B$21)` returns the position of the random number in the sorted random number list, `1..20`.
  - `=INDEX($A$2:$A$21, ... )` returns an item from your data set, based on the random rank from above.

Note: This will return a new randon sample each time Excel recalculates.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make a random selection that does not repeat is to make an array of integers, than randomize it, and than take out one by one.

For example you start with:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7

you randomize it (swap elements randomly)

2 4 5 1 7 3 6

than you take elements out one by one. (keep an index of how much elements you used in some cell)

Comment: I just want to use the numbers in the range of A2:A21  and randomly select one to put into cell C2, then D2, then E2, then F2, then G2, lastly H2, WITHOUT using the same number twice.
.                                                                 .
.                                                                 . 
Something like this (but this doesn't work):
.                                                                 .
C2 = Rand(a2:a21) D2 = If(value of D2 = C2, then Rand(A2:A21) again
.                                                                 .
.

Comment: There is no solution with functions for your problem. The only way is the one I described, you have to remember old random numbers somewhere somehow.

Answer (score 0):

[image: random trick]

Ok here is one trick, add another column with random numbers, than select both random column and range column and click the sort button (picture is from libreoffice but there is a similar button in excel) This will randomize your range column. Than you simply assign values to "w-1" : "w-6" like this =B2, =B3, =B4, =B5, =B6, =B7

I tried this and it works like you wanted, the only problem is it will shuffle values in your range column.

Comment: Note that w-3 and w-4 are the same because they are duplicated in range column, so it is not an error.